# How can I stop $.post in jQuery working asynchronously?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following calls:

```
getData(0);
getData(1);
getData(2);
```

These call a javascript function:

```
function getData(Code) {
  $.post('/adminA/GetData',
                { Code: Code },
  function (data) {
```

The problem is that my data gets returned out of order. Is there a way that I can have the data return in order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling these three ajax requests synchronously will freeze your browser.  You'd be better off using jQuery's Deferred objects.  Try this:

```
function getData(Code) {
    return $.post('/adminA/GetData', { Code: Code }, function (data) {/*etc.*/});
}

getData(0).done(function() {
    getData(1).done(function() {
        getData(2);
   });
});
```

#### Addendum

You should also consider combining your calls into a single one, and change the server logic to handle it.  This will ultimately be faster than three requests:

```
function getData(firstCode, secondCode, thirdCode) {
    $.post('/adminA/GetData', {
        codeOne   : firstCode,
        codeTwo   : secondCode,
        codeThree : thirdCode
    }, function (data) {/*etc.*/});
```

Answer (score 17):

Another alternative is to use ajaxSetup

```
function getData(Code) {
  $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
  $.post('/adminA/GetData',{ 
        Code: Code },  function (data) {
         // Do Something
        }); 
   $.ajaxSetup({async: true}); //So as to avoid any other ajax calls made sybchrounously
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use $.ajax instead and set async to false.

Comment: Specifically:  `$.ajax({ asynch: false });`  Then you should be able to do your $.post() as normal.

Comment: It is  `$.ajax({async: false});` just to correct spell

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$.ajaxSetup({ asynch: false })` as from jQuery documentation:

**jQuery.ajaxSetup( options )**

**options**

A set of key/value pairs that configure
 the default Ajax request. All options
 are optional.

This will setup options for all `ajax` request using jQuery.

Comment: It is `$.ajax({async: false});` just to correct spell

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer says, you can use $.ajax instead and set async to false.  However, this is going to hang the browser until all calls complete.  I would instead have each ajax call call the next one in line in its callback.  This way it remains asynchronous so it does not hang the browser.

Something like:

```
 function getData(Code) {
    $.post('/adminA/GetData',
                { Code: Code },
                function (data) {
                    getData(Code+1)
                });
 }
```

Obviously with something to tell it when to terminate.