# Trying to run javascript AJAX calls in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was trying to run three calls to AJAX and the following was suggested to me:

```
function getData(Code) {
    return $.post('/adminA/GetData', { Code: Code }, function (data) {/*etc.*/});
}

getData(0).done(function() {
    getData(1).done(function() {
        getData(2);
   });
});
```

When I run the code it gives an error saying `getData(0)` is undefined. When I run the code like this it runs fine but data comes back out of sequence:

```
 getData(0);
 getData(1);
 getData(2);
 getData(3);
```

Does anyone know why the first solution doesn't work. Seems like it's trying to execute `.done` on something it doesn't know about.

Comment: Can you add a link to where this was suggested to you? Are you using jQuery? Which version?

Comment: If I just inject this code on this page, I don't get that error.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me.  Please post the exact error message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326450/how-can-i-stop-post-in-jquery-working-asynchronously

Comment: retrieveData(0) is undefined
http://127.0.0.1:84/adminQ#
Line 82

Comment: so where's your `retrieveData()` function?  It's not in your posted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted code looks fine to me.

I put a copy at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/G8tmp/ and it works as required.

You reported an error in `retrieveData()` but no such function exists in your posted code.

Comment: Sorry I meant getData() just trying something different at that time

Comment: I marked your solution as correct because I took your fiddle, copied/pasted into my code and then added things to it. My code now works.  It appears I was missing the "return" before $.post Thanks to you and to everyone else that helped me.

Comment: @Mika that would do it.  I did wonder whether the posted code was actually the same as the code you were running... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `$.post`, and then trying to define a `done` event after the call.

I know it's ugly, but I'm guessing the following will work:

```
$.post('/adminA/GetData', { Code: 0 }, function (data) {/*etc.*/}).done(function(){
    $.post('/adminA/GetData', { Code: 1 }, function (data) {/*etc.*/}).done(function(){
        $.post('/adminA/GetData', { Code: 2 }, function (data) {/*etc.*/}).done(function(){
            $.post('/adminA/GetData', { Code: 3 }, function (data) {/*etc.*/});
        });
    });
});
```

Some nifty refactoring should help you reduce this.

Comment: in jquery 1.5+ it's perfectly valid to define and add a `.done()` _after_ the `$.post()`

Comment: @Alnitak - can you explain how this applies?

Comment: @Mika sure, when I get back from lunch... :)

Comment: @Mika `$.post()` now returns a `Deferred` object.  If you call the `.done()` method on that object it checks whether the deferred object is already "resolved", and if so invokes the callback immediately. Otherwise, it adds the callback to a queue of functions to be called later.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the function getData to receive the callback function. Like this:

```
function getData(Code,done) {
    return $.post('/adminA/GetData', { Code: Code }, function (data) {if(typeof(done)=='function') {done();} /*etc.*/});
}
```

So later to get the AJAX called sequentely just call it like this:

```
getData(0,function() {
    getData(1,function() {
        getData(2);
   });
});
```