# How to get variable from jQuery to function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

But for some reason, when i put variable **data** into **naughty**, it does not have content of **data**.

```
function cookie() {
    var naughty = 'aaa';
    $.post('/cookie', function(data) {
        naughty = data;
    });
    alert(naughty); // sends "aaa"
}
```

Why?

**UPDATE:** thank you! now i got it, its because $.post() is async, so alert(naughty) will be executed *before* it will be filled with **data**.

Now i have **sub-question**: when i turn off async, will only function cookie() postpone execution or whole browser engine will freeze until AJAX is done?

**UPDATE 2:** Yes, @Kevin B, you are right, **naughty** is never filled... i did mistake in first code sample. I am lucky that all answers are valid anyway with only second code sample :-)

As @Kevin B pointed out, async=false will be depreciated in jQuery 1.8. And it freezes browser until request is done...

**sub-question #2:** i have more code inside cookie(), after this AJAX request. So, can i somehow pause execution of cookie() untill AJAX is done, without freezing whole browser with async=false? Or do i have to find new way (using complete/success callback) of coding this idea?

LAST EDIT:
I realized that what i want is ASYNC:FALSE... So i simply used it. BTW. ASYNC:FALSE will NOT be removed from jQuery! Only special kind of use-case will be...

Comment: because the alert is hitting before your post is finished.  alert from within the post complete func and you'll see the dif

Comment: The first snippet should be alerting `aaa` not `bbb`, are you sure it's `aaa`?

Comment: To answer your update question, yes.  If async is false, the entire function will freeze until the server response comes back.  That could lead to problems.  Instead, it is probably better practice to handle all of your execution within the processing function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a race condition.  As .post() is an asynchronous function, the alert executes before naughty gets reset to data.

If you want the response to come back before continuing, you can use .ajax and set async to false.

[How can I stop $.post in jQuery working asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326450/how-can-i-stop-post-in-jquery-working-asynchronously)

Comment: Add that `async:false` is depreciated in jQuery 1.8

Comment: Oh Kevin, you just broke my heart.  I didn't know they were canning it.  I like having the synchronous options sometimes.  :-(

Comment: :-P  Thanks paradox.  I'm drinking a beer to celebrate tonight.

Answer (score 4):

Just do this:

```
function cookie() {
    var naughty = 'aaa';
    $.post('/cookie', function(data) {
        naughty = data;
        callNaughty(naughty);
    });
    
}

function callNaughty(naughty) {
  alert(naughty); 
}
```

**OR**

```
function cookie() {
    var naughty = 'aaa';
    $.post('/cookie').done(function(data) {
        naughty = data;
        alert(naughty)
    });
}
```

As `$.post()` is asynchronous, so `naughty` will update after response arrived.

#### Note

`async: false` is deprecated in jQuery 1.8

Answer (score 1):

This is because $.post is asynchronous. Execution leaves that line immediately while page is being requested and function(data) is yet to be called so data is empty. The empty data is what alert picks up. This can only work after the request has completed e.g. in synchronous fashion in which the alert statement has to wait

Answer (score 0):

Since `$.post` it's an `ajax` request, it's asynchronous by nature, so what you'd want to do it's to make sure that after you `ajax` request has been completed, then do whatever you want:

```
function cookie() {
    var naughty ;
    $.post('/cookie', function(data) {
        naughty = data;
    }).done(function(){
        alert(naughty);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that $.post is working asynchronously. So your alert is being called before the post callback has been executed. If you place the alert in the post callback you should get the correct result.